# How to (re-)assign an incremental number to each database row, having one sequence per user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table that stores pictures for a user, together with the 1-based position they should appear in:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Picture (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  position INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX (user_id)
);
```

It's currently filled with broken positions, such as:

| id | user_id | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 1 | 6 |
| 6 | 1 | 7 |
| 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 8 | 1 | 8 |
| 9 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**How can I reassign 1-based positions to the pictures of each user?** While keeping the original `position` order (modulo duplicates). So that it becomes:

| id | user_id | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 8 | 1 | 8 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**I'd like to do this with SQL queries only.**

Test data you can use to demonstrate your solution:

```sql
INSERT INTO Picture VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 1, 3),
    (4, 1, 5),
    (5, 1, 6),
    (6, 1, 7),
    (7, 1, 7),
    (8, 1, 8),
    (9, 2, 2),
    (10, 2, 3),
    (11, 2, 4),
    (12, 2, 5),
    (13, 2, 5),
    (14, 2, 5),
    (15, 2, 8),
    (16, 2, 9),
    (17, 2, 10),
    (18, 2, 12),
    (19, 2, 12);
```

**Please do not rely on the `id` column for ordering**: the order of `id` is only coincidentally the same as the order of `position` in this example, but it's not the case in the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest not doing an actual update, but rather just creating a view or select which generates the `position` output you want.  On MySQL 8+, we can try using `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
SELECT id, user_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY position, id) AS position
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 2, 3;
```

### Demo

Note that the above does rely on the `id` column to break a tie #when two or more records for a given user happen to be tied with the same `position`.

Comment: Thank you, however your query above yields: `[HY000][4016] Window function is not allowed in window specification`?

Comment: @BenMorel You are not running my code, which is working in the demo with your table definition and data as given above.

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot that I'm on MariaDB 10.5, not MySQL 8.0 on this project :'( Any chance you know a solution that would work with MariaDB? If not, no worries, I'll accept your answer and create another question specifically for MariaDB.

Comment: Very strange... `ROW_NUMBER` has been supported on MariaDB since v. `10.2`.  Please see if you can fix my answer.  Most likely, only some small change is needed.